# Create a dynamic case when statement based on pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a dataframe called `df` with `features, col1, col2, col3`. Their values should be combined and produce a result. What result each combination will produce is defined in `mapping_table`.

However, mapping_table sometimes has the value '*'. This mean that this feature can have any value, it doesn't affect the result.

This makes a join impossible(?) to make, since I need to evaluate which features to use in the join for every row.

What would be a good pyspark solution for this problem?

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

# Create a Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("example").getOrCreate()

# Example DataFrames
map_data = [('a', 'b', 'c', 'good'), ('a', 'a', '*', 'very good'), 
          ('b', 'd', 'c', 'bad'), ('a', 'b', 'a', 'very good'),
          ('c', 'c', '*', 'very bad'), ('a', 'b', 'b', 'bad')]

columns = ["col1", "col2", 'col3', 'result']

mapping_table = spark.createDataFrame(X, columns)


data =[[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'a', 'b' ), 
        ('c', 'c', 'a' ), ('c', 'c', 'b' ),
        ('a', 'b', 'b'), ('a', 'a', 'd')
      ]]

columns = ["col1", "col2", 'col3']
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
```

Comment: can you give an example of a sample input and the expected ouput ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transform `map_data` into a [case statement](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.5.0/api/sql/index.html#case):

```python
ressql = 'case '
for m in map_data:
    p = [f"{p[0]} = '{p[1]}'" for p in zip(columns, m[:3]) if p[1] != "*"]
    ressql = ressql + ' when ' + ' and '.join(p) + f" then '{m[3]}'"
ressql = ressql + ' end'

df.withColumn('result', F.expr(ressql)).show()
```

`ressql` is now

```sql
case 
  when col1 = 'a' and col2 = 'b' and col3 = 'c' then 'good' 
  when col1 = 'a' and col2 = 'a' then 'very good' 
  when col1 = 'b' and col2 = 'd' and col3 = 'c' then 'bad' 
  when col1 = 'a' and col2 = 'b' and col3 = 'a' then 'very good' 
  when col1 = 'c' and col2 = 'c' then 'very bad' 
  when col1 = 'a' and col2 = 'b' and col3 = 'b' then 'bad' 
end
```

Result:

```
+----+----+----+---------+
|col1|col2|col3|   result|
+----+----+----+---------+
|   a|   b|   c|     good|
|   a|   a|   b|very good|
|   c|   c|   a| very bad|
|   c|   c|   b| very bad|
|   a|   b|   b|      bad|
|   a|   a|   d|very good|
+----+----+----+---------+
```

Comment: Thanks, great! One comment thou, when I apply your logic to my use case dataset I need to use "for m in map_data.collect()" - otherwise I only loop column names(?) and not the rows.

Comment: I assume that `map_data` is a standard Python [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list) of [tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple), as given in the question. You are right if `map_data` is a Spark dataframe you should [collect](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.5.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.collect.html) the data first to the driver.